# Include file not found in include path

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I installed Visual Studio Code (version 1.12.1) and the extension ms-vscode.cpptools (version 0.11.0). Then I installed Windows 10 SDK tools (that includes the "Windows Kits" folder).

Now, I have a script like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    double a=sqrt(5), b=12345678;
    int count=6;
    cout.width(20);
    cout.precision(count);
    cout<<a<<" "<<b<<endl;
    printf("a=%3.8f b=%12f\n",a,b);
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Where the three `#include`'s at the beginnig are underlined in red. Then I clicked on one `#include` and selected "Add include path to settings", I updated the file `c_cpp_properties.json` but it still underlines the `#include` entries.

I have already created the file `c_cpp_properties.json` and it looks like this:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "F:/UTILITY/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.15063.0/ucrt/*"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE"
            ],
            "browse": {
                "path": [],
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
                "databaseFilename": ""
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

(I removed the "Mac" and "Linux" voices from the code above, but they are still in the original code)
`F:/UTILITY/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.15063.0/ucrt/*` is where my Windows Kits SDK is located.

Please help me!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: not really a help since + don't have windows, but <math.h> is for C, it should be <cmath> on c++.

Comment: Maybe, but also <iostream> and <cstdlib> are underlined in red.